# How to customize touch interaction on leaflet maps

Tags: maps, touch, leaflet, interaction

How to customize leaflet maps to disable one-finger scroll on mobile devices and add two finger scroll like google maps (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction)

I think something like a listener on finger down and finger up and a custom overlay or sth. like that should help. But how to correctly integrate this as a plugin in leaflet?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script>
      var mymap = L.map('mapid', {center: [48,9], zoom:8, layers: [L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')]});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sample map added. Normal behaviour: Map movement if touch begins in map box. I search for a solution to only scroll the map, if two fingers are used (e.originalEvent.touches.length == 2), otherwise the page should be scrolled.

Comment: BTW there is a [feature request for this in Leaflet's UserVoice](https://leaflet.uservoice.com/forums/150880-ideas-and-suggestions-for-leaflet/suggestions/17510338-a-gesturehandling-option-to-l-map).

Comment: If you're looking for Google style gesture handling, check out this question: [Leaflet JS - Implementing Gesture Handling to enforce 2 fingered scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095270/leaflet-js-implementing-gesture-handling-to-enforce-2-fingered-scrolling)

Answer (score 25):

Simply set the [`dragging` option of your map](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-dragging) to `false`, but be sure to keep the [`touchZoom` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-touchzoom) as `true`. This will disable one-finger dragging, while allowing the user to perform pinch-zoom with two fingers, which also pan the map around.

If you want this behaviour only in mobile devices, use [`L.Browser.mobile`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#browser-mobile) to set the value of the `dragging` option, as in

```
var map = L.map('map', { dragging: !L.Browser.mobile });
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a solution to allow dragging the map and the page (like described in the link above). The map needs to be dragged also, but if the map covers most of the screen on mobile devices, its impossible to scroll the page back to top.

Comment: So are you saying that you have tried this and it doesn't work?

Comment: Shure, with this option, dragging the page is possible but dragging the map isn't possible anymore with one, two or more fingers. Also, zooming the map isn't really possible anymore because page is scrolling with two fingers, too.

Comment: I tried to add an overlay which gets ex.originalEvent.touches.length and temporary disable map dragging at touchmove event. But the event needs to be fired before touchmove to get the correct result...

Comment: Hhhmmm, this is weird, I'm getting `pointercancel` events when dragging with two fingers, and that was completely unexpected. Consider opening a bug report at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues

Comment: I have evaluated your approach on some other devices to get more info before opening a bug report. On iOS devices it seems to work but on Android/Chrome it doesn't...

Comment: also pinch to zoom isn't possible then

Comment: Are there any updates or threads for this? I tried this solution and it works really well on Android (one finger scrolls page, two fingers drags map), but on iOS its getting weird (one finger does nothing - no page scroll, no map drag, two fingers are fine).

Comment: Ok, I found a solution [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5425#issuecomment-342055520). I would recommend include this into answer for next users.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working solution founded [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5425#issuecomment-342055520). All credits to @BlueManCZ comment

```
L.map('map', {
    dragging: !L.Browser.mobile,
    tap: !L.Browser.mobile
})
```

Answer (score 3):

As mention in comment by [Corrodian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6266185/corrodian), you can find GestureHandling plugins on Leaflet.

It was created by [elMarquis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271125/elmarquis) in can be found here https://elmarquis.github.io/Leaflet.GestureHandling/examples/

I've done with this plugins by including css and js after leaflet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet-gesture-handling.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/leaflet-gesture-handling.min.js"></script>
```

And add *gestureHandling* option in map like this:

```
var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [-25.2702, 134.2798],
    zoom: 3,
    gestureHandling: true
});
```

It works!

Comment: This plugin is better than simply adding options to the Map object. Because it can avoid page from scrolling while panning with two fingers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = L.map('map', {dragging: false});
map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
```

-or together-

```
var map = L.map('map',{dragging: false}).setView([lat, lng], zoom);
```