# Avoid pan and zoom of embedded OSM maps in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, openstreetmap

I have several embedded maps on [my website](https://inliner-rheinmain.de/mein-besuch-im-lausitzer-seenland-v-13-08-22-08-2021/). The source of these maps are from....

- [Plugin WP GPX Maps](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gpx-maps/)
- [uMap (iframe)](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/de/)

I want to avoid panning and zooming when swiping with one finger on smartphone. Panning and zooming should be only possible by using two fingers.

Accordingly using a computer dragging and zooming should be only possible by pressing the CTRL-key when using the mouse.

Is there a plugin for Wordpress or a code for css or functions.php to realise this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the leaflet map plugin](http://%20https://github.com/bozdoz/wp-plugin-leaflet-map) and set dragging to false and keep touchZoom on true.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41631385/288568